# Dragonfly BSD 6.2 on Vultr: No Disk Space

Tags: unix, bsd, vultr, dragonfly-bsd

Has anyone had any luck installing Dragonfly BSD 6.2 on Vultr (either as Cloud Computing / High Frequency VM)?

For me, it can't find any disk space - see picture. [image: Dragonly FLY BSD 6.2 can't seem the storage space on a Vultr node]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely their vm do not use recognized controller. You can try to login as root instead of installer and execute command:

`pciconf -lv | grep SCSI` or `pciconf -lv | grep SATA`

to show which SCSI or SATA controller is visible to Dragonfly. Then you will need to load driver for it using `kldload` and restart installer.